# How do you get text from a JTextArea in another class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Here the class object is called 'c1' and the JTextArea is called 't2'. The error Im getting says that 'The field UserInterface.t2 is not visible'.

```
String text = c1.t2.getText();
```

Comment: so provide a getter in that class, through which he can access it

Comment: I have one already, this the getter.

Comment: public String getAddress()
 {
  return t2.getText();
 }

Comment: Is this already covered by this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703439/java-field-is-not-visible

Comment: So why are you trying to access the "t2" variable? Why doesn't your code invoke the getAddressMethod()?